# Web Inspector on iPhone 6 simulator not showing the Elements tab

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, macos-catalina, xcode11

Im using the iPhone 8 (iOS 13.5) and the iPhone 6 (iOS 12.4) Simulator on my MacBook Pro running Catalina, and the Web Inspector in my Safari desktop browser works great.  I can see the Network tab, the Elements tab, etc while using both simulators in the Web Inspector.  But when using the Web Inspector for the iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3.1) simulator, I cannot see the Network tab or the Elements tab.  I only see Sources, Audit and Console tabs.  I would like to be able to see the Network tab and Elements tab when running the Web Inspector on the iPhone 6 simulator (iOS 10.3.1).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the Safari Technology Preview for everything to work properly.

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/